Cricket out via Wicket keeper removing the stump on a free ball
A batman was facing a free ball following a no ball, he advanced a couple of yards to hit a spinner, missed the ball and retreated, the wicket keeper broke the wicket and lifted a stump out of the ground before the batsman had made his ground. No other fielder touched the ball and it was in the wicket keepers control at all times. The decision was out run out. Is this correct?

Pedantically, a "free ball" is not defined in the Laws of Cricket; this question can be answered only be referring to the Playing Conditions for the specific tournament it occurred in.
However, on the assumption that this occurred in a tournament using a close variant of the current (December 2023) Men's One Day International playing conditions, we can refer to Law 21.19.2:

For any free hit, the striker can be dismissed only under the circumstances that apply for a No ball, even if the delivery for the free hit is called Wide.

We can then refer to Law 38 Run Out (which is essentially identical between the Laws and the Playing Conditions), which states:

38.2.2 The striker is not out Run out in any of the circumstances in 38.2.2.1 and 38.2.2.2.
38.2.2.1 He/She is out Stumped.

and Law 39 Stumped (again essentially identical):

39.1.1 The striker is out Stumped, except as in 39.3, if a ball which is delivered is not called No ball and he/she is out of his/her ground [...] and he/she has not attempted a run when his/her wicket is fairly put down by the wicket-keeper without the intervention of another fielder. [...]
39.1.2 The striker is out Stumped if all the conditions of 39.1.1 are satisfied, even though a decision of Run out would be justified.

Your case sounds like all the conditions for being out stumped were met:

The ball was not a no ball: it was a free hit
The batter was not attempting a run
No other fielder intervened

Therefore this was a stumping, and the batter was not out run out via 39.1.2 / 38.2.2.1. I would say the decision was incorrect, but you politely should ask the umpire(s) for their explanation.

The playing conditions states:

For any free hit, the striker can be dismissed only under the circumstances that apply for a No ball, even if the delivery for the free hit is called Wide.

Assuming a free hit has the same dismissal requirements as a No-ball, the  conditions provide for run out that:

38.2.2 The striker is not out Run out in any of the circumstances in 38.2.2.1 and 38.2.2.2.
38.2.2.1
He/she is out Stumped.
38.2.2.2
No ball has been called and he/she is out of his/her ground not attempting a run and the wicket is fairly broken by the wicket-keeper without the intervention of another fielder.

I believe therefore that the batter is not out Stumped, as that dismissal can not be effected on a free hit, and is not out Run out either, as 38.2.2.2 prevent a Run out in the circumstance of a no-ball stumping, and likewise a free hit stumping.

38.2.2.2 specifies that the batter is not run out, not that they cannot be out at all. It's effectively the mirror of 39.1.2 which makes it clear that a stumping takes "priority" over a run out.

@PhilipKendall Actually 38.2.2.1 is that a stumping takes "priority" over a run out, and 38.2.2.2 prevents a no ball stumping from being counted as a run out.
